# Why is my collapsible text showing up adjacent to the span rather than inside it?

Tags: html, css

Trying to work with Bootstrap collapsibles.  I want my collapsible info to display below the pic, inside the span classed "gameContainer".  Instead, it spawns adjacent to it.  Here is the "minimum reproducible" example of my problem:

```
    <head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class ="flex-container">
    
    <a href ="#oblivion" data-toggle="collapse"><span class = "gameContainer"><img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/The_Elder_Scrolls_IV_Oblivion_cover.png" class = "game">
    </a>
        <span id = "oblivion" class="collapse">
        <br>
        Elder Scrolls IV: Oblivion
    </span>
    <!-- only if you put the "a" tag down here rather than up there does it come out right(ie)
    show up below the game's pic.  This is true if the tag for the "oblivion" span is span or a div-->
</span>
    


</div>
</body>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body
{
    padding: 20px 40px;
}

img
{
    width: 150px;
}

.gameContainer
{
    padding: 40px;
    margin:  0px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.gameContainer:hover
{
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 70%);
    border-radius:10px;
    
}

.game
{
    border-radius: 10px;
}   

.flex-container
{
     display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) to column makes it:

```css
.flex-container
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```